# NoSuchMethodError: getSize

Tags: android

I have the following code to find the size of the screen:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Point size = new Point();
    int measuredWidth = 0;
    int measuredHeight = 0;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);

        measuredWidth = size.x;
        measuredHeight = size.y;
    } else {
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

        measuredWidth = display.getWidth();
        measuredHeight = display.getHeight();
    }
```

On a galaxy gio (2.3.6) this works, but on a galaxy tab 10.1 (3.0) this crashes.

```
wm.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
```

On this line I get

> NoSuchMethodError: android.view.Display.getSize.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already found it, I tought that the getSize() method was available since HoneyComb (api 11), but it's actually only available since Honeycomb_MR2 (api 13).

Answer (score 0):

getSize() is since API 13 [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getSize%28android.graphics.Point%29)

You probably run this on a device having an older version.

Try getHeight() and getWidth().